# Compositing images by blurred mask in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library, bitwise-or

I have two images and a mask, all of same dimensions, as Numpy arrays:

[image]
[image]
[image]

## Desired output

I would like to merge them in such a way that the output will be like this:

[image]

## Current code

```py
def merge(lena, rocket, mask):
    '''Mask init and cropping'''
    mask = np.zeros(lena.shape[:2], dtype='uint8')
    cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, circle, 255) # might be polygon
    '''Bitwise operations'''
    lena = cv2.bitwise_or(lena, lena, mask=mask)
    mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask) # mask inverting
    rocket = cv2.bitwise_or(rocket, rocket, mask=mask_inv)
    output = cv2.bitwise_or(rocket, lena)

    return output
```

## Current result

This code gives me this result:

[image]

Applying `cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (51,51), 0)` distorts colors of overlayed image in different ways.
Other SO questions relate to similar problems but not solving exactly this type of blurred compositing.

### Update: this gives same result as a current one

```py
mask = np.zeros(lena.shape[:2], dtype='uint8')
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (51,51), 0)
mask = mask[..., np.newaxis]
cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, circle, 1)
output = mask * lena + (1 - mask) * rocket
```

## Temporal solution

#### Possibly this is not optimal due to many conversions, please advise

```
mask = np.zeros(generated.shape[:2])
polygon = np.array(polygon, np.int32) # 2d array of x,y coords
cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, polygon, 1)
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (51, 51), 0)
mask = mask.astype('float32')
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
foreground = cv2.multiply(lena, mask, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
background = cv2.multiply(rocket, (1 - mask), dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
output = cv2.add(foreground, background)
```

Please advise how can I blur a mask, properly merge it with foreground and then overlay on background image?

Comment: What kind of blend are you looking for? Multiplicative? Additive? `alpha * x + (1-alpha) * y`? Try a couple in the image editing software of your choice (Photoshop/GIMP/Paint.NET/...).

Comment: @MateenUlhaq just applying blurred foreground on top of background is enough, all this in order to achieve Desired output as shown in the post, thanks for clarification

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I suppose this has something to do with RGB channels but not sure; I read somewhere that it could be achieved using `PIL.Image.composite(lena, rocket, mask)` but don't know yet how to properly convert arrays back and forth

Comment: Have you tried the simple alpha blending method I mentioned? `output = mask * lena + (255 - mask) * rocket`, where `mask` has been blurred as desired.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Yes, it gives `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shape (225, 400) with (225, 400, 3)`, possibly because of mask

Comment: `mask = mask[..., np.newaxis]` should make it broadcastable.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq so some reason it inverts the whole picture, also I can see that `lena` isn't blurring at edges

Comment: @MateenUlhaq but if I fill `convexPoly` with 1s instead of 255 and instead `(255 - mask) * rocket` make `(1 - mask) * rocket`, then it gives a normal picture same as my current result (not blurred)

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I have updated the post, please take a look

Comment: It doesn't look like you blurred the mask, which is why it's still just a regular filled circle.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq yep, I apply it right after the initialization and get the same result, take a look at updated post, thanks

Comment: That will only blur by `51/3 = 17` pixels at most. Try a more drastic blur method. One simple way is probably some sort of radial blur.

Comment: I mean, you don't even need to blur anything since it's a perfect circle anyways. Just use a source function. For example, r = |x - x0|. f(r) = 1/r^2 * exp(-r)

Comment: @MateenUlhaq just tried with `(101,101)`, same results. Btw my circle coordinates are of type `np.array([[x,y],[x2,y2]], np.int32)`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I need smooth gradient at edges and it might be a polygon as well, hence `cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, polygon, 1)`

Comment: Use 255 for your mask maximum value. The cv2 gaussian blur is probably just setting it to 0 and 1 for a np.uint8. Make sure it displays a properly blurred mask on your screen. You can convert to np.float32 and divide by 255 afterwards.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq using 255 gives me inverted image, really weird, but I have added a temporal solution, please take a look if it's even optimal or not

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Essentially it is the same approach as you recommended, but with heavy conversions on the fly, I am not sure it's even optimal

Comment: Do you mean "temporary" solution? To confirm, is it producing the desired result and the only problem is that it's slow?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Yes, the temporal solution works as expected and I haven't felt that it's slow, BUT maybe you know how to optimize/refactor it, since I am quite new to OpenCV and Python in general and I suspect that it's not very efficient, since it actually makes the same using more ops. Are there any other ways to do the same in Numpy?

Comment: You should run a profiler (or time it manually, I suppose) to check which line is the one causing the slowdown. My guess is the Gaussian blur.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq got it, thanks! Also found that if my polygon intersects the image edge (coords are out of image range), then no blurring where it intersects (blurring cut out). Don't know how to address this, probably should make a new question.

Comment: For that, you can probably draw your polygon in the center of the mask, blur it, then shift it to the desired location. Also, you don't need a mask that is the size of the entire image -- that's a bit wasteful, computationally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do that in Python/OpenCV. Your second method is close.

- Read the 3 input images
- Apply linear (or Gaussian) blur to the circle
- Stretch the circle to full dynamic range (0 to 255) as a mask
- Convert the mask to float in the range 0 to 1 as 3 channels
- Apply mask to image1 and inverted  mask to image2 via multiplication and add the products together
- Convert the result to 8-bit range (0 to 255) clipping to be sure no overflow or wrap around
- Save the results

Input images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read images
image1 = cv2.imread('lena_wide.jpg')
image2 = cv2.imread('rocket.jpg')
circle = cv2.imread('white_circle.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# linear blur mask
mask = cv2.blur(circle, (30,30))
# alternate using Gaussian blur
#mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(circle, (0,0), sigmaX=10, sigmaY=10)

# stretch mask to full dynamic range
mask = cv2.normalize(mask, None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)

# convert mask to float in range 0 to 1
maskf = (mask/255).astype(np.float64)
maskf = cv2.merge([maskf,maskf,maskf])

# apply mask to image1 and inverted  mask to image2
result = maskf*image1 + (1-maskf)*image2
result = result.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)


# save results
cv2.imwrite('white_circle_ramped.jpg', mask)
cv2.imwrite('lena_wide_rocked_composited.png', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Ramped mask image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

ADDITION:

Here is an alternate approach using mostly Numpy.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read images
image1 = cv2.imread('lena_wide.jpg')
image2 = cv2.imread('rocket.jpg')
circle = cv2.imread('white_circle2.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# linear blur mask
mask = cv2.blur(circle, (30,30))
# alternate using Gaussian blur
#mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(circle, (0,0), sigmaX=10, sigmaY=10)

# stretch mask to full dynamic range
mask = cv2.normalize(mask, None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)

# convert mask to 3 channels
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])

# apply mask to image1 and inverted  mask to image2
image1_masked = np.multiply(image1, mask/255).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
image2_masked = np.multiply(image2, 1-mask/255).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# add the two masked images together
result = np.add(image1_masked, image2_masked)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('white_circle_ramped2.jpg', mask)
cv2.imwrite('lena_wide_rocked_composited2.png', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("image1_masked", image1_masked)
cv2.imshow("image2_masked", image2_masked)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much for this! Could you please tell would there be any notable difference in time complexity, etc. between direct Numpy arrays manipulations and OpenCV `multiply/add` methods if there are any? I remember your help with ffmpeg years ago, thanks again!

Comment: I cannot say for sure, but I would expect that doing it this way will be a slower, but I do not know by how much. You would have to do time tests to determine that properly.  Please identify the exact processing your propose.

Comment: See @shortcipher3 solution below. It is like my Numpy solution, but using OpenCV multiply and add. Probably the simplest method. All OpenCV is likely optimized and can be run via GPU if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to renormalize the mask before blending:

```
def blend_merge(lena, rocket, mask):
    mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (51, 51), 0)
    mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    mask = mask.astype('float32') / 255
    foreground = cv2.multiply(lena, mask, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
    background = cv2.multiply(rocket, (1 - mask), dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
    output = cv2.add(foreground, background)
    return output
```

A full working example is [here](https://github.com/shortcipher3/stackoverflow/blob/master/compositing_images_by_blurred_mask_in_numpy.ipynb).